# Best way to determine whether a FQCN is a class, interface, or trait

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to determine whether a FQCN is a class, a trait, or an interface. This is what I am currently thinking of, but does anyone have any better ideas?

```php
/**
 * @return string|null Returns the type the FQCN represents, returns null on failure
 */
function fqcnType(string $fqcn) : ?string
{
    if (interface_exists($fqcn) === true) {
        return 'interface';
    } elseif (class_exists($fqcn) === true) {
        return 'class';
    } elseif (trait_exists($fqcn) === true) {
        return 'trait';
    } elseif (function_exists($fqcn) === true) {
        return 'function';
    }

    return null;
}

function fqcn_exists(string $fqcn) : bool
{
    return fqcnType($fqcn) !== null;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
/**
 * @return string|null Returns the type the FQCN represents, returns null on failure
 */
function fqcnType(string $fqcn) : ?string
{
    $types = [
        'interface',
        'class',
        'trait',
        'function',
    ];

    foreach($types as $type) {
        if(true === ($type.'_exists')($fqcn)) {
            return $type;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

function fqcn_exists(string $fqcn) : bool
{
    return null !== fqcnType($fqcn);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Though I would normally agree with Toby Speight's comment about why a code snippet is a good solution, in **this particular case** the code is the documentation. It is readable, concise, and even built with maintainability in mind. I would like to see more contribution from this user, and more answers which are so clear as to **not need auxiliary documentation**.